# NodeJS express-session обновление сессии

Tags: node.js, сессия

В общем проблема такая, понять никак не могу.
Я создаю сессию на 1 минуту, перестаю пользоваться, она истекает.
Все как надо, после перезагрузки страницы доступа мне не дает.
Но тут такая проблема, в базе сессия просроченная остается.
И тут я пытаюсь авторизироваться вновь и мне не дает!
Авторизируюсь и получаю тот же результат что с просроченной сессией.
Далее замкнутный круг, авторизироваться вновь мне просто не предоставляется возможным.
До тех пор пока я не удалю сессию с базы данных.

```
var sessionOptions = {
    secret: "secretsessionslalal",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new PostgreSqlStore({
        //postgres://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST_NAME:PORT/DB_NAME
    }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 60000),//1800000), 
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60000)//1800000) 
    }
};


app.post('/', function(req, res) {
   sess = req.session;
   var user = req.body.username,
       pass = req.body.password;

   sess.user = user;
   console.log(user);
   console.log(pass);

   res.redirect('/logged'); 
});

app.get('/logged', function(req, res) {
    sess = req.session;
    if(!!sess.user) {
        res.send('Добро пожаловать, '+sess.user+'! (<a href="/logout">Выйти</a>)'); 
    }
    else { 
        res.send('Get out!'); 
    }
});
```

Сейчас заметил еще один прикол. Попытался залогиниться под другим пользователем, сессия зашла в базу уже просроченной. От чего такое может быть?

Comment: Еще раз проверил. Получается вообще никак залогиниться обратно не выходит. С какого бы юзера я не пытался зайти.

Comment: Похоже понял проблему. Время в любом случае в базу заходит от запуска программы. Вопрос тогда в том, как сделать дабы время было от нынешнего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был прост:

```
maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 60000), 
expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60000)
```

Меняем на:

```
maxAge: 60000, 
expires: 60000
```